# How to exclusively compile a custom source for OpenLayers 3

Tags: javascript, node.js, openlayers-3

I have created a new Source for OpenLayers 3 that works similarly to *[ol.source.ImageWMS](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/blob/master/src/ol/source/tilewmssource.js)* but with a modified request structure since the remote source is not a WMS.

The new source work as expected when used together with *ol-debug.js* or if compiled together with the OpenLayers library as a [*custom build*](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.5.0/doc/tutorials/custom-builds.html).

But what I want is so exclusively compile my extension and then include it in my project as an extension to OpenLayers.

For example

```
<script src="ol.js"></script>
<script src="imageSpecialSource.js"></script>
```

I have tried to exclude the some of the library symbol names / patterns under the export section in the json config file. But including the compiled js file will make OpenLayers to throw an error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: a.cf is not a function
```

So, is it possible to compile a custom extension exclusively that can then be included as a separate file?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, know that there's a more **up-to-date** tutorial that explains how to compile OpenLayers 3 along with your own library.  See here: http://openlayers.org/en/v3.14.1/doc/tutorials/closure.html

The compilation process requires a `config.json` file.  Here's a snippet of the config file from the above tutorial:

```
{
  "lib": [
    "node_modules/openlayers/src/**/*.js",
    "node_modules/openlayers/build/ol.ext/**/*.js",
    "src/**/*.js"
  ],
  "compile": {
    "closure_entry_point": "app",
    "externs": [
      "node_modules/openlayers/externs/bingmaps.js",
      "node_modules/openlayers/externs/closure-compiler.js",
      "node_modules/openlayers/externs/geojson.js",
      "node_modules/openlayers/externs/proj4js.js",
      "node_modules/openlayers/externs/tilejson.js",
      "node_modules/openlayers/externs/topojson.js"
    ],
    ...
```

See that in it, what's inside `lib` gets compiled together, that's OpenLayers and your own custom code.

Then, look at the `externs` section. These defined externs files that allow the code to be used within ol3 without the Closure Compiler complaining about classes and methods it would otherwise not know about.

In order to compile your code **without ol3**, you could remove it from the `lib` section and add the `ol3 extern file` in `externs` instead. In ol3, that file is located in `build/ol-externs.js`. If it's not there, you can generate it by running:

`node tasks/generate-externs.js build/ol-externs.js`

You can take a look at the OL3-Google-Maps library that does exactly that.  Its `dist/ol3gm.js` file doesn't contain OpenLayers: https://github.com/mapgears/ol3-google-maps/

Look at the json config file, which is named `ol3gm.json`: 
https://github.com/mapgears/ol3-google-maps/blob/master/build/ol3gm.json.  You'll see that the `ol-externs.js` file is used in there.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I followed the link and I can see that they can end up with a dist file to be included in a script tag, but I cannot really follow exactly what step they have made to end up there. A bit more detailed description would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Sorry for replying so late. I tried again, but still cannot manage to create a successful build even with the extern file included. If I try to compile with my extension as the only source, it will fail due to the dependencies i.e. ol.Map etc. If I have the full source, but exclude all but my extension, the resulting file will be similar to what I had before, e.g. OL will throw an error (Uncaught TypeError: a.cf is not a function)